# How to get a String in a StringList ? C#

Tags: c#, xml, string, parsing, tstringlist

I have a small problem with my Exchange Appointment. The idea is to sync a meeting from sharepoint calendar to the personal exchange calendar.

I have this StringList in my CalendarItem Class:

```
   private StringList m_Category;
   public StringList Category { get { return m_Category; } }
```

And there it should go:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment xApointment = new Appointment(m_Service)
xApointment.Categories = xItem.Category; //xItem = Instance of CalendarItem
```

In the `Microsoft.Exchange.WebService.Data.Appointment` I have the predefinied `StingList Categories`.

What happens now is that I'm parsing through an XML File which looks like:

```
<listitems  xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
    xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
    xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
    xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <rs:data ItemCount="1">
    <z:row  ows_ContentTypeId="0x010200C5A7325634A3154BB8249D1C36246E00" 
    ows_Title="Test GetAllViewFields" 
    ows_Location="Testhausen" 
    ows_EventDate="2014-12-15 08:00:00" 
    ows_EndDate="2014-12-15 09:00:00" 
    ows_Description="Ein Test meeting" 
    ows_fAllDayEvent="0" 
    ows_fRecurrence="0" 
    ows_EventType="0" 
    ows_RecurrenceID="2014-12-15 08:00:00" 
    ows_Duration="3600" 
    ows_ParticipantsPicker="" 
    ***ows_Category="Geschäftlich"***
```

And than I'm parsing this whole XML Code as a String and check if the name is there:

```
private void initFromXmlAttribute(System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute x)
    {
        string AttributeName = x.Name.LocalName.Replace("ows_", "");
        try
        {
            if
            (AttributeName == "Category")
            {
                m_Category= x.Value; //Error implicite convert not possible StringList to String
                return;
            }
```

The Error is because `m_Category = StringList` and `x.Value = String`.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve this little issue?

Comment: Change m_Catgory to be type of string!

Comment: Hey @Sajeetharan, thanks for your fast answer
already did that, but than I have a problem at `xApointment.Categories = xItem.Category;` because xApointment from the Microsoft Class is a StringList and that one can't be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with class StringList, but I guess it a Collection.
You can simply initialize a new StringList with the string inside it :

```
m_Category = new StringList() { x.Value };
```

Comment: Great @Nir thanks, didn't thought it was "that easy" if I do it that way :) you just made my morning ;)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about [this class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.stringlist%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), you'll see that [its constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee693861(v=exchg.80).aspx) accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`, so you can write:

```
m_Category=new StringList(new[]{x.Value});
```

StringList implements IEnumerable so you can also use the collection initializer syntax:

```
m_Category=new StringList{x.Value};
```

This creates the class in two steps - first creates an empty object and then calls `Add` for each item in the initializer

Comment: Thank you @Panagiotis for your shared knowledge, you guys are great !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a new Stringlist with the desired values (StringList [inherits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.stringlist.aspx) from List(Of String), so it's quite straightforward:

```
myStringList = new StringList()
myStringList.add(x.Value)
```

Btw since you are effectively setting your "Category" Property you might want to consider including a "set" statement to your property instead of modifying your private variable directly. In fact you can skip defining your private variable completely by using:

```
public StringList Category { get; set; }

Category = new StringList()
```

The compiler will do the rest for you.

Comment: @H W thanks for your reply, but I think I will leave it the way how Panagiotis and Nir explained. but about the get / set, that's a nice point, thanks